# arduino mega multi integer values reading on other arduino mega

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, string

I need two Arduino communications.
The master arduino from the slave arduino needs to read 16 signals.
The sample serial port output from the slave is as follows.

```
@ 125 @ 13 @ 874 @ 1023 & 950 @ 547 @ 965 @ 852 @ 654 @ 478 @ 0 @ 456 @ 996 @ 789 @ 556 @ 847 @
```

I need to throw this output into an integer array.

Comment: So the problem is only to split up the received string? Then maybe [this article](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/splitting-text-c) from Majenkos Blog can help you

Comment: Is the `&` a typo? Should that have been `@`? Also, are there line endings added after each block of 16 values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following C functions:

- `strtok`: to split a string (see [strtok](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)).
- `atoi`: to convert a string to an integer (see [atoi](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)).